# Routing in Angular 9

Tags: typescript, angular, angular-routing

Вопрос: Как настроить роуты что бы я мог зайти по ссылке к примеру site.com/test/tes53 и что бы меня правильно редиректило. А то у меня когда ввожу такую ссылку в url он не находит данный путь и кидает на 404. Т.е как сделать что бы сайт правильно понимал роуты из строки а не идти все шаги с главной.

p.s Всем спасибо

Comment: А что туториалы пишут?

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам пример роутов для site.com/test/tes53. Может пригодится.

```
 const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    children: [
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent,
        children: [
           path: 'test53',
           component: Test53Component,
        ]
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent },
];
```